# How to Holiday day Variable in Regression model?

Tags: r, linear-regression, feature-selection, lasso-regression

I want to build a regression model with a dataset that contains Holiday days such as , ,"Christmas","New year","17th of May - National day","Easter","Kr. Himmelfart (Ascension day)","Pinse","Summer vacation"

I want to predict the response variable which is the total sales of meat. My code is like this:

```
    data=as.data.frame(scale(data))
    
  
    model=cv.glmnet(trainX, train$meat, alpha=1,family="gaussian")
    model$lambda.min
```

I scaled the whole data (including the holidays) and performed the linear regression with Lasso, the holidays all have negative coefficients(considerably larger than other intercepts). My question is should I remove the holiday days before building the model or should I keep them?

Comment: Since you're asking about interpretation ("... should I remove"), your question is better suited to stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package called [`linea`](https://www.linea-r.org), which supports linear regression in R.

- The function `get_seasonality` adds seasonality variables to a data frame.

  - dummies for each week, month, year, Christmas, and easter...
- The `gt_f` function appends google trends data to a data frame

  - a time series that can act as a proxy for social trends (e.g. Christmas season) instead of having dummies

Here is some code that shows how to generate various seasonal variables and build a linear regression model with them.

```
library(linea)
#devtools::install_github('paladinic/linea')
#https://www.linea-r.org/
library(tidyverse)

df = linea::sales_ts

df = df %>% 
  get_seasonality(date_col_name = 'week',date_type = 'weekly starting') %>% 
  gt_f(kw = 'christmas',date_col = 'week','weekly starting',append = T) %>% 
  gt_f(kw = 'national day',date_col = 'week','weekly starting',append = T) 

colnames(df)
# > .. "christmas_day" "christmas_eve" "new_years_day" "easter" "good_friday"...

dv = 'sales'
ivs = c('christmas_all_gt',
        'national day_all_gt',
        'christmas_day',
        'easter')


model = run_model(data = df,dv = dv,ivs = ivs)

summary(model)

model %>% 
  decomp_chart()
```

Output:

```
Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          346159.0    16404.8  21.101  < 2e-16 ***
christmas_all_gt      -3269.9     1065.4  -3.069  0.00263 ** 
national day_all_gt   -1538.5      652.8  -2.357  0.01999 *  
christmas_day        376510.3   479534.4   0.785  0.43385    
month_Dec            -49871.8    67281.9  -0.741  0.45994    
easter              -554740.7   337343.5  -1.644  0.10260    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 82260 on 125 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3494,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3234 
F-statistic: 13.43 on 5 and 125 DF,  p-value: 1.769e-10
```

[image]